# AJAX Load Content and Pass Variable (POST)

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to pass a href-attribute to a content I'd like to load with AJAX, but I'm not able to find the right solution for this.

```
<a href="test">Link</a>
```

I know how to pass a simple value ...

```
var data = { id: 123 };
$('.container').load( 'content.php', data );
```

But how can I pass a variable?

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('.container').load( 'content.php', ???????????? );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well you want to do this:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('.container').load( 'content.php', { href:href });
```